# Pattern substitution and delete the resulting line

Tags: linux, sed

I need to substitute a pattern, let's say  (the symbols need to be too) to a NULL string.

If this results in an empty line, the line should be deleted. It explicitly says that curly brackets may be needed to make this happen, and here is where I get stuck.

I can easily substitute the pattern but not delete it as the "s" command in sed does not accept my syntax:

This is what I tried:

```
sed 's/<"patern">//{/g/d}' file.txt
```

Edited: I put it like this because it gets it like an HTML header.

Maybe the curly brackets are to specify somehow if the resulting line from substituting is empty do something else?

Comment: Hint: *"if the line contains the pattern, then {excise it; if nothing is left, delete the line}"*

Comment: @Beta yes but what's the way to use the curly brackets here? I read you can concatenate multiple functions to the "s" sed command but syntax is not working. I understand it like you, if the pattern is found in some line, delete it (substitute it to a null string) and if nothing is left delete the line but I don't know what's the possible/s way/s to do it with sed.

Comment: You seem to think that the `s` command is doing (or ought to do) everything. Let's start with something simpler: *if the line is empty, delete it.* Can you write a sed command to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can first match the pattern and replace it with an empty string.

Then check if the line is empty using for example a pattern `^$`, and if it is so, delete the line using `/d`

If you want to do multiple replacements, you can use `/g` like `s/<"patern">//g`

```
sed 's/<"patern">//;/^$/d' file.txt
```

Or using curly's

```
sed 's/<"patern">//g;{/^$/d;}' file
```

Comment: The approach is the same I had but the exercise explicitly says you'd probably need curly brackets and I wanted to do so. Is that possible? Also if I do it your way, I'd remove lines that already are in the file and are just newlines, so I'll remove all newlines present in the file which is not the purpose.

Comment: @kevin Like this? `sed  '/abc/{s/abc//g;/^$/d}' file` See https://ideone.com/oC8NiJ

Comment: Or just like `sed 's/<"patern">//g;{/^$/d}' file`

Comment: The output of either of both is the same :

sed: extra characters at the end of d command

I tried to used bash, zsh and sh and neither of these worked.

Comment: @kevin What is your OS? Did you check the demo link https://ideone.com/oC8NiJ? How are you using the pattern?

Comment: I'm in a Mac, running zsh / bash and not working in neither of both

Comment: @kevin I have updated the answer, I ran this on my mac and I had to add the `;` at the end.